# psycopg2 error if called via fcgi

Tags: python, apache, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask application I want to deploy on a shared host. It uses psycopg2 and is deployed via apache as a fcgi app via [flipflop](https://github.com/Kozea/flipflop). Everything works fine when tested or when manually called, even on the production server. That means I can do the following on the production server:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
$ python myapp.py
>>> from myapp import Post
>>> Post.query.all()
[<Post1>, <Post2>, ...]
```

But if accessed via fcgi via the apache server (e.g. visiting `mysite.com/all_posts` which is supposed to show all posts) the apache throws a 500 and the following error is logged:

```
ImportError: /home/syntonym/project/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: lo_truncate64
```

The psycopg2 FAQ has a note on that:

> if the message reports undefined symbol: lo_truncate64 it means that Psycopg was built with large objects 64 bits API support (i.e. the libpq used at compile time was at least 9.3) but at runtime an older libpq dynamic library is found.

and to avoid that problem:

> You can use:
>   `$ ldd /path/to/packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so | grep libpq`
>   to find what is the libpq dynamic library used at runtime.
>
> You can avoid the problem by using the same version of the pg_config at install time and the libpq at runtime.

```
$ ldd /home/syntonym/project/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so | grep libpq
libpq.so.5 => /package/host/localhost/postgresql-9.3/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fc4f7b30000)
$ pg_config
LIBDIR = /package/host/localhost/postgresql-9.3.2-1/li2b
```

I also tried to compile psycopg2 with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/package/host/localhost/postgresql-9.3.2-1/lib"`. `ldd` showed then the exact same lib as `pg_config`, but the same error persists.

The fgci script is as following:

```
#!/home/syntonym/project/env/bin/python3.4

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/syntonym/project")
print(sys.path)

from flipflop import WSGIServer
from myapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

My own files (myapp.py) are copied via scp, I installed the dependencies manually in a virtual env via pip (`pip install flask`, `pip install sqlalchemy`, `pip install psycopg2`, ...). Because the app is working in the absence of apache/fcgi I think everything on the python app is set up correctly.

Apache (2.2) uses mod_fcgid and suexec. Could it be that apache forces a different libpg.so by some environment variable or something?

Comment: How are you deploying the project to the remote?

Comment: @hd1 The python files are copied manually via scp. The apache is globally installed (version 2.2) and uses mod_fcgid and suexec (such that the fcgi scripts are executed with user rights). I'm not expirienced with apache or fcgi so if I'm missing critical information let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suexec does not carry over any environmental variables. A solution is to make another fcgi script and source the bashrc:

```
#!/etc/bin/env bash
source path/to/home/.bashrc
exec real_fcgi_script
```

or insert the path to libpg manually (i.e. in python via environ).

Answer (score 0):

Simply copying the python files over will not work if you have C code, which [psycopg2](http://init.org) includes. As a workaround for this, you can use the pure-python [pg8000](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000) or:

1. Create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/) using `virtualenv env`.
2. Install psycopg2 in said virtualenv -- `env/bin/pip install psycopg2`.
3. Generate requirements.txt -- `env/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt`
4. Copy `requirements.txt` over to your deployment server, if you're using version control, you should check this file in as well.
5. Repeat step 1 on the deployment server, but instead of step 2, type `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
6. Execute your python script **in the virtualenv**: `./env/bin/python foo.py`

Hope that helps. If you have further questions, please leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry, what I said is incomplyete. I only copied my flask app via scp, then I created a virtualenv with `python -m venv env`, and then I installed my requirements manually (typing `source env/bin/activate` `pip install flask` ... `pip install psycopg2`). After that didn't work out I got the [source of psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/download/) and made it via `python setup.py make` and `python setup.py install` (with python from the venv). The error is still the same.

Comment: This needs to be added to your question